# How to implement PoE access points?

Tags: networking

I want to setup a Network with up to 8 PoE access points, that are connected either to main switch or a secondary switch that is connected to the main switch in the building, and not all access points will be connected directly to the main switch, so the question is:

To have PoE access points in different locations of network should I buy a PoE capable switch for the main server room, or for all locations, or use a PeE injector for main or all?

Or maybe I have to use a separate PoE injector for each AP?

For better explanation I have attached a simple network diagram.

[image: for better explanation I have attached a simple network diagram.]

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a PoE capable Main Switch will not enable PoE for devices connected to Second and Third Switches. Power supplied by the Main Switch will not be transferred over other switches.

If you need PoE for all access points your options are:

- No switch is PoE capable: You use PoE injectors for each AP
- All switches are PoE capable: No need for PoE injectors
- Mix and Match: Some switches may be PoE capable, PoE injectors can be used for AP that are not connected to PoE switches. (ex: Main Switch is PoE capable, others are not -> PoE injectors to be used for AP connected to Second and Third Switches)

If not all AP need PoE, probably using PoE injectors at these AP will be cheaper and easier.